# SugarORM + Android Studio + Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, sugarorm

I am trying to create a basic Book CRUD which works fine in the application code but I am trying to write unit tests for that entity.

During non-testing normal use, the Android manifest Application tag defines an application called "com.orm.SugarApp". This always gets called upon start up and it becomes the ApplicationContext at run time.

However, when I run my unit tests that extends InstrumentationTestCase, I find the breakpoints fire in the tests but com.orm.SugarApp Application is not initialized. The constructor for com.orm.SugarApp does not get invoked before the CRUD calls are made.

How can I configure Android Studio/Gradle to execute unit tests with com.orm.SugarApp as a prerequsite application already initialized.

Comment: nvm - I know now to use the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 which will establish the Application object as com.orm.SugarApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm - I know now to use the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 which will establish the Application object as com.orm.SugarApp